# share data from a custom grunt task with another grunt task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am relatively new to using grunt. I created a custom grunt task that queries my database to get a value, I want to add that value to a path in a grunt-contrib-copy task, to look like so:

```
{cwd: 'src/public/modules/' + variablefromCustomTask}
```

I have been unable to figure this out or find any useful resource online to help. 
Any ideas/link to a resource that might help?

Comment: Have you taken a shot at writing this yourself?  If so, can you post your code?

Comment: @jh314 Thanks, I found a way to go around this by using ncp (https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp) within my custom gruntfile for my recursive copy, that way I no longer need a grunt task for that purpose, Hence no need to share files across grunt tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: 
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option
Depending on necessity : 
https://github.com/TopCS/grunt-pg-utils
or
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-schema-update

Comment: Thank you. I found a way to go around this by using ncp (github.com/AvianFlu/ncp) within my custom gruntfile for my recursive copy, that way I no longer need a grunt task for that purpose, Hence no need to share files across grunt tasks.